# Building dashboard with Month sorted data validation drop-down

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown, dashboard

I'm trying to build a dashboard with a month sorted view - where in an ideal situation the user would select the month from the dropdown and the represented data would change accordingly.

So far my approach has been to query the data into a separate sheet using the drop-down option, but I'm facing a problem with the All option.

Example:

My drop-down contains months

Jan
Feb
Mar
...
...
All

This works until the "All" option is selected, as there is no All in my original data. I understand there's other formats of using a date range instead, but I'm curious to know how this can be done as well.

Do let me know if this needs to be clarified!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `IF` switch:

```
=IF(A1="All", QUERY(_full_query_here_), QUERY(_query_that_checks_A1_for_month_))
```